# How To Use Erlang ssl:close/2

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp, gen-tcp

I have an SSL server, and I want to downgrade this after receiving the first `ssl:recv` to a raw gen_tcp. Assuming this can be used to do that I can not find an example on how to use this. And I am not so good at using the Erlang/OTP documentation yet http://erlang.org/doc/man/ssl.html#close-2

I am a bit confused with `NewController::pid()` from the documentation:

```erlang
How = timeout() | {NewController::pid(), timeout()}
```

Answer (score 1):

`NewController::pid()` here refers to the process you want to set as the "controlling process" for the downgraded TCP socket. `gen_tcp` functions on the socket will only work if called from that process. You'll want to send `self()` here unless you want to use the downgraded TCP socket from another process.

The only example I could find of `ssl:close/2` being used with a tuple as the second argument is [this test](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/48e35d38d7625a10395b03edb4337668abaa4905/lib/ssl/test/ssl_basic_SUITE.erl#L4792-L4812). Here's a simplified version of that code to get you started:

```
% Assuming `SSLSocket` is the SSL socket.
{ok, TCPSocket} = ssl:close(SSLSocket, {self(), 10000}),
% You can use `TCPSocket` with `gen_tcp` now.
gen_tcp:send(TCPSocket, "foo"),
```

Comment: I get an error, timeout when I do this.  "In the latter case the transport connection will be handed over to the NewController process after receiving the TLS close alert from the peer."  -- Does the peer(client) need to send something special?